# Selenium Element Location

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

Is there an easy way to find a child element from another element (both of these items have been located using a PageFactory)?  We have a set of containers which hold many modules, and I'd like to ensure that they are displaying in their proper locations.

The API only seems to have the following method:

```
webElement.findElement(s).(By by);
```

Is there an easy way to do the following:

```
webElement.findElement(s)(WebElement webElement);
```

or even better:

```
webElement.contains(WebElement webElement);
```

Comment: I can't really figure out what are you trying to do. Could you please give an example? From what I udnerstood, the `element.findElement(s)(By by)` should be good enough even for your needs. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I would prefer not to utilize reflection again to pull the FindBy annotation off of the fields.  I have two elements which have already been initialized with a custom PageFactory.  We have many different modules which can be created and added to various pages.  I don't want to modify each of these tests whenever the pages are changed in the CMS, as such I'm self-locating these modules and am now wanting to verify that they exist in the proper locations on the screen (i.e. I want to ensure that Module A is in Container A or B, but not C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got what you need. My best solution would be something in the way of:

```
public static void assertContains(WebElement outerElem, WebElement innerElem) {
    // get borders of outer element
    Point outerLoc = outerElem.getLocation();
    Dimension outerDim = outerElem.getSize();
    int outerLeftX = outerLoc.getX();
    int outerRightX = outerLeftX + outerDim.getWidth();
    int outerTopY = outerLoc.getY();
    int outerBottomY = outerTopY + outerDim.getHeight();

    // get borders of inner element
    Point innerLoc = innerElem.getLocation();
    Dimension innerDim = innerElem.getSize();
    int innerLeftX = innerLoc.getX();
    int innerRightX = innerLeftX + innerDim.getWidth();
    int innerTopY = innerLoc.getY();
    int innerBottomY = innerTopY + innerDim.getHeight();

    // assures the inner borders don't cross the outer borders
    final String errorMsg = "ughh, some error message";
    final boolean contains = (outerLeftX <= innerLeftX)
            && (innerRightX <= outerRightX)
            && (outerTopY <= innerTopY)
            && (innerBottomY <= outerBottomY);
    assertTrue(errorMsg, contains);
}
```

...works only if none of those containers overlap. If they do, I'd try some dark and wild magic with `innerElem.getTag()` and `getText()` and test whether the outer text contains the inner element. One way of doing it:

```
public static void assertContains(WebElement outer, WebElement inner) {
    // e.g. //div[text()='some text in inner element']
    final String findInner = ".//" + inner.getTagName() + "[text()='" + inner.getText() + "']";
    try {
        outerElem.findElement(By.xpath(findInner));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ignored) {
        fail("Some horrible message! We are all doomed!");
    }
    // passed
}
```

...or something similar. It is possible that [normalize-space()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) or [contains()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) (or both) will be needed due to tags in tags in tags in...

And, of course, this is still guessing. The first method may have false positives and negatives (but I like it more given my needs), the second should only have false positives. You can combine them or invent something yourself (e.g. using `Reflection` as you have already stated).

Or [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry).

Comment: While I'm not necessarily in love with this method, it does offer the benefit in that we should be able to determine if browsers are rendering the HTML in a similar fashion to one another, however that's a double-edged sword as well, as the HTML may in fact be a child of the element, but not within it's boundaries if we get a hosed result from the driver due to rendering issues.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not the thing we actually would like to have =/. Also, I edited the answer to be more useful for future readers (as you seemed pretty much capable yourself), by the way.

Comment: Looks good, I'm more than likely just going to work on a custom locator, as I think it will be a bit cleaner.  I'm also going to post this on the selenium google code repository as a feature request.

Comment: Or that. Funny, I haven't thought about that _at all_.

Comment: In case you were curious, I passed in the parent element to the custom ElementLocatorFactory we created and catch the exceptions if not found in that particular WebElement (and filed issue 3682).